# How To Access hash maps key when the key is an object

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I cannot seem to figure out how to access the values of my hashmap

What I am basically trying to do is create a hashmap with an array as one of the values like json style.. If that makes sense?

So I want something like `hash{key: value1, value2, value3, [number1,number2]}`

and be able to access it like (pseudocode:) `hash.get(3).get(1)`

```java
public class WebSearch {

readFile.ReadFile xfile = new readFile.ReadFile("inputgraph.txt");
HashMap webSearchHash = new HashMap();
ArrayList belongsTo = new ArrayList();
ArrayList keyphrase = new ArrayList();


public WebSearch() {




}


public void createGraph()
{
    HashMap <Object, ArrayList<Integer> > outlinks = new HashMap <Object, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < xfile.getNumberOfWebpages(); i++ )
    {
        keyphrase.add(i,xfile.getKeyPhrases(i));
        outlinks.put(keyphrase.get(i), xfile.getOutLinks(i));

    }

}
```

`keyphrases` is an `ArrayList`

this is my output of `System.out.print(outlinks);`

`{[education, news, internet]=[0, 3], [power, news]=[1, 4], [computer, internet, device, ipod]=[2], [university, education]=[5]}`

How would I go about getting say just this: `[education, news, internet]=[0, 3]`

I have tried:

`outlinks.get(xfile.getKeyPhrases(i))`

`xfile.getKeyPhrases(0)` would for example return `[education, news, internet]`

Comment: Even if they declared type is Object, HashMap uses the equals and hashCode methods for the actual key object. What is their class? It is not Object, because the output did not come from Object's toString.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the key set ([Map.keySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29)) of the map first; `outlinks.keySet()`

Then you can use these keys on your map to get your entries (values of the keys)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted enough of the surrounding code for your question to be entirely clear, but look at [the Javadocs for `Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). You will probably get what you want by iterating over `outlinks.values()`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a customized object and use it inside your collections.

You may create a POJO/Bean class and overwrite the toString method with the details that you want, for instance the a iterate over items inside a array.
When you use it to print or display the toString method will be call.

The following link show you some ideas:

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object

Answer (score 0):

You can access the keys of any HashMap using [Map.keySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) method.

Also note that `java.util.HashMap` is unordered. HashMap makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

You would like to relook at the structure of your HashMap, you are having `ArrayList` as your key.