# Java, hashmap inside a hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

follow up from my question here: [How To Access hash maps key when the key is an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983696/how-to-access-hash-maps-key-when-the-key-is-an-object/17983787?noredirect=1#17983787)

I wanted to try something like this: `webSearchHash.put(xfile.getPageTitle(i),outlinks.put(keyphrase.get(i), xfile.getOutLinks(i)));`

Wonder why my keys are `null`

here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

import readFile.*;

public class WebSearch {

    readFile.ReadFile xfile = new readFile.ReadFile("inputgraph.txt");
    HashMap webSearchHash = new HashMap();
    ArrayList belongsTo = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList keyphrase = new ArrayList();

    public WebSearch() {        
    }

    public void createGraph()
    {
        HashMap <Object, ArrayList<Integer> > outlinks = new HashMap <Object, ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < xfile.getNumberOfWebpages(); i++ )
        {
            keyphrase.add(i,xfile.getKeyPhrases(i));
            webSearchHash.put(xfile.getPageTitle(i),outlinks.put(keyphrase.get(i), xfile.getOutLinks(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

when I do `System.out.print(webSearchHash);` the output is `{Star-Ledger=null, Apple=null, Microsoft=null, Intel=null, Rutgers=null, Targum=null, Wikipedia=null, New York Times=null}`

However `System.out.print(outlinks);` gives me : `{[education, news, internet]=[0, 3], [power, news]=[1, 4], [computer, internet, device, ipod]=[2]}` Basically I want a hashmap to be a value of my key

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "keys are `null`". The key to a `Map` is *always* an object of some sort. What output are you getting that makes you think your keys are `null`?

Comment: Are you sure that xfile.getPageTitle(i) is not returning null?

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't use a `HashMap` (or any mutable object) as your key, since it will destabilize your `Map`.  Depending on what you're intending to accomplish, there may be a number of useful approaches and libraries, but using an unstable object as a `Map` key is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

So figured I just do this which gives exactly what I want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < xfile.getNumberOfWebpages(); i++ )
    {
        HashMap <Object, ArrayList<Integer> > outlinks = new HashMap <Object, ArrayList<Integer>>();
        keyphrase.add(i,xfile.getKeyPhrases(i));
        outlinks.put(keyphrase.get(i), xfile.getOutLinks(i));
        webSearchHash.put(xfile.getPageTitle(i), outlinks);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are putting in null with this statement

```
 webSearchHash.put(xfile.getPageTitle(i),outlinks.put(keyphrase.get(i), xfile.getOutLinks(i)));
```

lets break it down. a put is of the form

```
map.put(key,value)
```

so for your key you have `getPageTitle(i)`. which is fine

for your value, you have the return value of

```
outlinks.put(keyphrase.get(i), xfile.getOutLinks(i))
```

according to the javadoc, a hashmap put returns the previous value that was associated with this key (in this case keyphrase.get(i)) or null if no value was previously associated with it.

Since nothing was previously associated with your key, it returns null.

So your statement effectively is saying

```
webSearchHash.put(xfile.getPageTitle(i),null);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K, V)